# SQL Server 2012 CDC not working on certain tables only

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, change-data-capture

I am using SQL 2012 sp3.  I have CDC working on many tables and DBs without issue.

Last night a change was put into the system and 2 of my CDC'd tables were dropped and modified without properly removing CDC on those tables beforehand (it was done without my knowledge).  I can no longer get CDC to work on those 2 tables.

I found the old capture instances for the tables and dropped them.  When I add them back in, everything goes in error free, but CDC captures no data and `select sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn` returns NULL.

I have tried adding/dropping the captures several times, adding data to the tables myself just to make sure some changes were going in, stop/starting SQLAgent and running the cleanup job.  I also tried adding the captures back in under different a different name.  Nothing works.

When I add both captures back in;
`sys.sp_cdc_help_change_data_capture` shows both of my captures.  `select sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('Capture_table1')` returns null. `sys.dm_cdc_errors` is empty.   `select * from  cdc.Capture_Table1_CT` has no data in it (even though I made sure to add some data changes).  My Agent and SQL logs are clean.

I read that running `sp_repldone` can cleanup the log and may help CDC, however I hesitate to do that as this is running on an Availability Group and I am concerned it may have negative effects.

Is there anything else to try?

Comment: does `SELECT *
FROM cdc.change_tables` show the correct object_id values for the tables in question?

Comment: It does have the correct object_id values.

Comment: I fixed my issue.  It was a much larger problem.  I started troubleshooting with a very narrow scope -- just the 2 tables that were effected by the change.  It turns out that all of my CDC for the entire server was down.  Upon further investigation I realized that it was the AG that was causing this.  We had a power outage days before and one of my replicas was still down. As a result the log was not hardened and CDC stops recording changes.  Once I pulled my 3rd replica off of the AG all of CDC started working.

Comment: If you care to share some details about the steps you took, you could answer your own question, which may help someone in future.  If you do that, you may want to [edit] your question if necessary.